# Use Columns From One Left Joined Table In Second Left Joined MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say that we need something like this query:

```
SELECT table1.c1, table1.c2, c3, c4 FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c1II, c3II as c3 FROM table2) joined1 ON table1.c1 = joined1.c1II

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c1III, c4II as c4 FROM table3 WHERE c4 > joined1.c3) joined2 ON table1.c1 = joined2.c1II
```

I tried to run this query and got the following error:

> Error in query (1054): Unknown column joined1.c3 in where clause

What should I do to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT table1.c1, table1.c2, c3, c4 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN  table2 ON table1.c1 = table2.c1II
LEFT JOIN  table3 ON c4 > table2.c3 AND table1.c1 = table3.c1II
```

Comment: Can't believe it's so simple, Thank you